# Are there any issues in applying Oracle 9.2.0.8.0 patch set on Windows 2003 server?

Tags: oracle9i

I'm going to apply an Oracle 9.2.0.8.0 patch to an existing 9.2.0.7.0. The server has Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition SP1.

Are there any issues/problems you encountered after applying this 9.2.0.8.0 patch set in Windows 2003?

Answer (score 1):

We've found Oracle 9i to behave pretty well on Server 2003. We've patched both 8i an 9i to higher versions on a 2003 server and all patches went off without a hitch.

Having said that though, always make sure you FULLY READ Oracle's patch instructions and readme's because they really like to hide gotchas in there.